Why pg.mixer.music.get_busy() returns False if music is playing
I was making an mp3 music player for myself. When pausing is enabled(key down), everything is fine, but if you turn off the pause, it skips the current music, although it should not do so.
I've already tried a lot of things, but I still don't understand what's wrong with the code. I would be very grateful if you could help me.
code -
import os
import pygame as pg
from random import *

Mlist=[]
Mlist=os.listdir("playlist")
shuffle(Mlist)#getting a music list from a folder "playlist"

pg.init()
size = [800, 600]
screen = pg.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pg.time.Clock()
pause = False
running = True
pos=0
while running:   
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:#pause music (key down)
            if pause:
                pg.mixer.music.play(0)
                pause = False
            else:
                pause = True
                pg.mixer.music.pause()
    if Mlist and not(pg.mixer.music.get_busy()) and not(pause):
        song = choice(Mlist)
        Mlist.remove(song)
        pg.mixer.music.load("playlist/"+song)
        pg.mixer.music.play()
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
quit()


You are playing the music back from start = 0 after unpausing
Here's the documentation for that function
pygame.mixer.music.play()
Start the playback of the music stream
play(loops=0, start=0.0, fade_ms=0) -> None

When you pause you should capture at what point the song was paused at, then pass that in to the play function
ie.
          if pause is False:
                unnormalized_position = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
                position_music = float(unnormalized_position / 1000)
                pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            else:
                pygame.mixer.music.play(0, position_music)

